# Linux - distorted sound from X application

Tags: linux, x11, audio

I have recently set up an interesting, simple/lightweight system mail notification for my Devuan Beowulf installation which got me more or less what I wanted.

```
~$ uname -a
Linux devuan 5.10.0-0.bpo.3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.13-1~bpo10+1 (2021-02-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
~$
```

Simple in that it was MTA only (no POP/SMTP/etc.) and lightweight because it had to be independent and do *just* that: notify me of system mail. ie: not integrated to a panel or desktop.

I was forgetting to check my system mail regularly.

The application is called `Coolmail`, it's ca. 1995 (!).

Besides firing up a mail utility such as `mutt`, `mailx`, etc., it has is the option of playing a sound alert. ie: a system beep through the on-board hardware's piezo or a sound file through external speakers.

I cannot seem to get the system beep to be loud enough and the application is rather dated so it uses OSS drivers, support for which was dropped in around the 4.15 kernel version. (?)

My installation has Pulse Audio installed and I've never paid much attention to it save to raise the main volume when I'm listening to music or watching a movie.

My box does no games and I'm *still* using the same Sony SRS-PC30 active speaker system I reluctantly purchased (whatever for?) along with a SB16 ISA card back in 1995 ($$$).

In any case, I was unable to get a `*.au` sound file played as `coolmail` complained of not being able to write to `/dev/audio` which was not present in my file system.

Seems Linux sound is a complicated thing.

After a while I came across a post (sorry, lost the link) that gave indications for installing the `oss-compat` package, which I promptly I did.

Doing so removed `osspd-pulseaudio` which made me grin.
I'll look into ripping out the rest of it further on.

Sorry, I digress ....

Now I have `/dev/audio` in my system, along with `/dev/dsp` and `/dev/mixer` which were already present:

```
~$ ls -l /dev/ | grep audio
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio      14,   4 Jul  4 15:53 audio
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio      14,   3 Jul  4 15:53 dsp
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio      14,   0 Jul  4 15:53 mixer
~$
```

Now the `*.au` file `coolmail` could not play *is* played but unrecognizably distorted even if I drop the volume, so that would not seem to be the cause.

And I am `still` getting an error from the application:

```
~$ coolmail -v
Coolmail 1.3 watching file: /var/spool/mail/groucho
Coolmail: Error writing to /dev/audio.
--- snip ---
:~$
```

The file plays normally via `Audacious`, `VLC` and `aplay`:

```
~$ aplay -v /home/groucho/Downloads/ding.au
Playing Sparc Audio '/home/groucho/Downloads/ding.au' : Signed 16 bit Big Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Stereo
ALSA <-> PulseAudio PCM I/O Plugin
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S16_BE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 2
  rate         : 48000
  exact rate   : 48000 (48000/1)
  msbits       : 16
  buffer_size  : 24000
  period_size  : 6000
  period_time  : 125000
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : GETTIMEOFDAY
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 6000
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 24000
  stop_threshold   : 24000
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 6755399441055744000
~$
```

I did find a post from back in 1999 with the *same* problem but it never received a follow up.

http://www.linuxmisc.com/5-linux-hardware/5cb2489886e85949.htm

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance,

A.

Comment: As far as I know, `/dev/audio` is not even original to the OSS: it is/was a partial implementation (u-law encoding support only, differences in ioctls) of a similar device interface on old Sun SPARC workstations using Solaris OS. That's where the `*.au` sound file format comes from, too. The native device interface of OSS would have been `/dev/dsp`.

Comment: Yes, I've read from this all came from. Sun/SPARC/Solaris.

Comment: Yes, I've read from this all came from. Sun/SPARC/Solaris. But the thing is that the application wants to write to `/dev/audio` and does not succeed while at the same time producing a heavily distorted sound. Since it works with `aplay` I wonder if the distortion has to do with the file not being `raw` type instead of `.au`.